# SQL converting to LINQ, subquery gets called twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a raw SQL query I would like to convert to LINQ and execute with my SQLite db but have some serious problems:
The query is supposed to return me only 2 rows.

SQL code:

```
WITH XXXX("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
AS
(
SELECT "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" FROM "TABLEXYZ"
WHERE ("A" <> 0) AND ("B" = 32)
ORDER BY "C" DESC
)

SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM XXXX LIMIT 1)
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM XXXX WHERE ("F" = 0) LIMIT 1)
```

That what I though would work:

```
var query = dataStore.XXXXTable.Where(x => x.A != 0 && x.B == 32).OrderByDescending(x => x.C).AsCte();
XXXXData? lastData = query.FirstOrDefault();
XXXXData? lastCorrectData = query.FirstOrDefault(data => data.F == 0);
```

But it gives me an error:

The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I don't want it to be client evaluated.

These ones below seem to work but the query gets executed twice, or at least that is what LINQPad is indicating:

1: subquery gets called twice

```
var query = dataStore.XXXXTable.Where(x => x.A != 0 && x.B == 32).OrderByDescending(x => x.C);
XXXXData? lastData = query.FirstOrDefault();
XXXXData? lastCorrectData = query.FirstOrDefault(data => data.F == 0);
```

2: subquery gets called twice

```
Expression<Func<DbSet<XXXXTable>, IOrderedQueryable<XXXXTable>>>? query = (DbSet<XXXXTable> table) => 
table.Where(x => x.A != 0 && x.B == 32)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.C);    

var func = query.Compile();

// Yet another attempt - query executed twice
XXXXTable? lastData = func(dataStore.XXXXTable).FirstOrDefault(); 
XXXXTable? lastCorrectData = func(dataStore.XXXXTable).FirstOrDefault(data => data.F == 0);
```

3: subquery gets called twice

```
Expression<Func<DbSet<XXXXTable>, IOrderedQueryable<XXXXTable>>>? query = (DbSet<XXXXTable> table) => 
table.Where(x => x.A != 0 && x.B == 32)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.C);    

var func = query.Compile();
dataStore.XXXXTable.Select(x =>
    new 
    { 
        LastData = func(dataStore.XXXXTable).FirstOrDefault(),
        LastCorrectData = func(dataStore.XXXXTable).FirstOrDefault(data => data.F == 0)
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is it possible to have that subquery XXXX called only once, I know that I could get around this problem using LINQ aggregate but I can't seem to enforce EF Core LINQ to use WITH clause without runtime exceptions.

Comment: Yes the sub-query will get called twice -- why is that a problem?

Comment: Loading times, I call that method a few hundred times with different "B" arguments. I am trying to decrease the number of  queries send to DB.

I suppose the best case would be to just send a query with an array of different "B" arguments, That would end up being only 1 db access.

Comment: If you want me to help solve the problem you have to give the full specification of the problem.  My guess is that you want another table with the "B" arguements and then you want to do a join -- that is probably the best way to get results fast for an SQL system.

Comment: I have a few thousand sensors connected to my server, each sensor takes a measurement every n minutes and sends it to the server. The server has a class instance of each sensor, so when the server receives the data, it sets the sensor's LastMeasurement and LastCorrectMeasurement(if the measurement does not have any errors) Properties.
The server itself does a lot of math based on the sensor's LastMeasurement and LastCorrectMeasurement.

Comment: The problem is with startup times. When the server starts up it has to load the LastMeasurement and LastCorrectMeasurement of all sensors from the DB, and it takes quite some time.

Comment: So the SQL query you want is probably a ROW_NUMBER with a partition on the sensor and an order by on the timestamp desc -- then you select all with row number = 1 and you get a data set with all the values you need.  You can create a view to store this query and ten select from the view.

Comment: @Vite, `AsCte()` is not EF operator. Do you use linq2db extensions?

Comment: Yes, it is linq2db extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linq2db EF Core extension needs at least one `ToLinqToDB()` call to switch data provider. Also your query needs tuning.

```cs
var cteQuery = dataStore.XXXXTable
   .Where(x => x.A != 0 && x.B == 32)
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.C)
   .AsCte();

var lastData = cteQuery.Take(1);
var lastCorrectData = cteQuery.Where(data => data.F == 0).Take(1); 

var query = lastData.Concat(lastCorrectData);

// switch to alternative translator
query = query.ToLinqToDB();

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So the SQL query you want is probably a ROW_NUMBER with a partition on the sensor id and an order by on the timestamp desc -- then you select all with row number = 1 and you get a data set with all the values you need. You can create a view to store this query and ten select from the view

like this:

```
CREATE VIEW RECENT_SENSOR_DATA AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SENSOR_ID ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE DESC) AS RN
     FROM SENSOR_DATA_TABLE
   ) X
   WHERE RN = 1
)
```

Note -- I use * because I don't know the field names in your table -- you should use the actual field names in the final view to avoid all kinds of maintenance problems with using *